# Extracting and logging only value of a key in fluentd

Tags: fluentd, td-agent

I have an input file with JSON messages (line delimited). The format of the messages is as below.

```
{"level":"info","message":{"accountId":99,"end_dateTime":"","id":0.22837359658442535,"log":[]}}
{"level":"info","message":{"accountId":100,"end_dateTime":"","id":0.2583,"log":[]}}
{"level":"info","message":{"accountId":200,"end_dateTime":"","id":0.5783,"log":[]}}
```

I wanted to save the message part of it in the mongo database using fluentd. In mongo, the data in the collection should look like the below.

```json
{
    "_id": ObjectId("626a1b813c04335a858e5926"),
    "accountId": 99,
    "end_dateTime": "",
    "id": 0.22837359658442535,
    "log": []
}
```

I wanted to extract and save only the value of the `message` key of the input payload.

I have tried using the below config, but it is not working.

```xml
<source>
  @type tail
  @id input_tail2
  read_from_head true
  path "/opt/webhook-logs/webhook.log"
  pos_file "/opt/webhook-logs/webhook.log.pos"
  tag "td.mongo.events"
  <parse>
    @type "json"
    unmatched_lines 
  </parse>
</source>
<match td.mongo.**>
  @type mongo
  host "127.0.0.1"
  port 27017
  database "vonnect"
  collection "webhooklog"
  user "vonnect"
  password xxxxxx
  buffer_chunk_limit 8m
  time_key time
  <buffer>
    flush_interval 2s
  </buffer>
  <inject>
    time_key time
  </inject>
</match>
```

I have tried record transformer filter too but no success. The filter config looks like

```xml
<filter td.mongo.**>
  @type record_transformer
  renew_record true
  # enable_ruby
  # auto_typecast true
  <record>
    ${record["message"]}
  </record>
</filter>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's a working example with `record_transformer` and `parser` filter plugin:

**fluent.conf**

```xml
<source>
  @type sample
  @id in_sample
  sample [
    {"level":"info","message":{"accountId":99,"end_dateTime":"","id":0.22837359658442535,"log":[]}},
    {"level":"info","message":{"accountId":100,"end_dateTime":"","id":0.2583,"log":[]}},
    {"level":"info","message":{"accountId":200,"end_dateTime":"","id":0.5783,"log":[]}}
  ]
  tag sample
</source>

<filter sample>
  @type record_transformer
  renew_record true
  keep_keys message
  enable_ruby true
  <record>
    message ${record["message"].to_json.to_s}
  </record>
</filter>

<filter sample>
  @type parser
  key_name message
  reserve_data true
  remove_key_name_field true
  <parse>
    @type json
  </parse>
</filter>

<match sample>
  @type stdout
</match>
```

Run:

```sh
fluentd -c fluent.conf
```

Output:

```
2022-04-28 14:04:29.094892632 +0500 sample: {"accountId":99,"end_dateTime":"","id":0.22837359658442535,"log":[]}
2022-04-28 14:04:30.097973274 +0500 sample: {"accountId":100,"end_dateTime":"","id":0.2583,"log":[]}
2022-04-28 14:04:31.000677835 +0500 sample: {"accountId":200,"end_dateTime":"","id":0.5783,"log":[]}
```

`record_transformer` removes the extra keys and keeps `message` with its value converted to a plain string. `parser` then removes the `message` key and expands its string value as JSON.

References:

- https://docs.fluentd.org/filter/record_transformer
- https://docs.fluentd.org/filter/parser

Comment: I need output as 2022-04-28 12:46:52.038182958 +0500 sample: {"accountId":99,"end_dateTime":"","id":0.22837359658442535,"log":[]}. Message key shouldn't be there, only its value should be.

Comment: @AnkitRastogi: Answer updated. Please test this on your side. See if it works for your use case .