# Fluentd SQL output with complex JSON object failing with NULL value

Tags: fluentd

I'm trying to build a fluentd pipeline that pulls data from an API and puts it in PostgresQL:

```
<source>
  @type http_pull

  tag energydata
  url http://10.0.0.30:8080/data
  interval 10s
  format json
</source>

# Record from source looks like this (I've sent it to stdout to verify): 
# {
# "url":"http://10.0.0.30:8080/data",
# "status":200,
# "message":
#   {
#   "timestamp":"2022-12-01T09:28:43Z",
#   "currentPowerConsumption":0.429
#   }
# }

<match energydata>
  @type sql
  host 10.0.0.10
  port 5432
  database energy
  adapter postgresql
  username fluent
  password somepasswd

  <table>
    table energymeterdata
    column_mapping '$.message.timestamp:timestamp,$.message.currentPowerConsumption:currentPowerConsumption'
  </table>
</match>
```

The resulting SQL row contains only NULL values. What is the right syntax for the [record_accessor](https://docs.fluentd.org/plugin-helper-overview/api-plugin-helper-record_accessor) in the column_mapping?

I've tried different syntaxes and quote styles for the record_accessor use in the column mapping, but I can't find the right format.

Before knowing it should be possible with the record accessor (as claimed by one of the maintainers in a Github [issue](https://github.com/fluent/fluent-plugin-sql/issues/74)) I tried flattening the JSON structure, but I could not get that to work either. I prefer the approach mentioned in this post, because it is a cleaner solution. It seems this is a fairly basic scenario and I may be overlooking something.

Comment: Do you see any errors in the logs? It didn't work after flattening the JSON with `record_transformer`, right? If yes, please add that config to your question as well.

Comment: The only error I keep getting is that Postgres (rightfully) does not accept (null,null) as a valid row since there is a not null constraint on the timestamp.

Comment: @Ameen I was able to get the flattening to work in the 2 transformer steps you detailed in another post - thanks. I still would like to have the answer for doing it with the record_accessor, since that seems like a cleaner solution.

Comment: From the [parsing of the `column_mapping` field](https://github.com/fluent/fluent-plugin-sql/blob/a05003501dc65e121ed56aec59f5ea83eba9e665/lib/fluent/plugin/out_sql.rb#L140-L149) and the rest of the source, it doesn't look like it supports `record_accessor` syntax. It's a one-to-one mapping of keys (source fields of the internal msgpack) and values (destination columns of the table) so the transformation suggested in that issue should work.

Comment: Good to hear that! You're welcome! You might want to self-answer this question with the exact configuration that solved your issue for others. Thanks! The maintainers might add `record_accessor` support in the future. I see your reaction to another similar [issue](https://github.com/fluent/fluent-plugin-sql/issues/126#issue-1161116130).

Comment: Oh, I just saw this [comment](https://github.com/fluent/fluent-plugin-sql/issues/74#issuecomment-501963189) that the `record_accessor` is supported since v1. But, I'm not seeing anything related to that in the source. I'll go through the codebase thoroughly later. Your syntax looks correct though it's not working.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out there is nothing other than the comment from user 'repeatedly' in the Github issue to show that record_accessor syntax is supported in the sql column_mapping parameter. This means that we will have to rely on filters to modify the json structure. For me, the following configuration works:

```
<filter energydata>
  @type record_transformer
  renew_record true
  keep_keys message
  enable_ruby true
  <record>
    message ${record["message"].to_json.to_s}
  </record>
</filter>

<filter energydata>
  @type parser
  key_name message
  reserve_data true
  remove_key_name_field true
  <parse>
    @type json
  </parse>
</filter>
```

Source: [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72039142/extracting-and-logging-only-value-of-a-key-in-fluentd/72039887#72039887)